# Not enough whitespace when a Hot Meta Post has a triple-digit score

Tags: bug, sidebar

The title basically says it all. When a Hot Meta Post on the sidebar reaches a triple-digit score, the score and the title get "squished" together:

[image]

Can we get some whitespace between them?

System details:

- Browser: Google Chrome Version 74.0.3729.169 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Screen size: 15" (Dell Precision 5520)
- Screen resolution: 3840 x 2160

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The Hot Meta Posts vote counter is too narrow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384507/the-hot-meta-posts-vote-counter-is-too-narrow) or [Spacing on “Hot Meta Posts”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384858/spacing-on-hot-meta-posts)